# How to read excel into Julia?

Tags: excel, julia

I need to read an excel file into Julia. I tried the package "ExcelReaders". However, the package requires additionally the Python or the xlrd package. Although it uses the conda.jl package to install these dependencies automatically, I keep on running into different installation problems. Is there a simple way to read excel into Julia? Has anyone tried the Taro.jl package?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Taro.jl package works well to read excel into Julia. You can install the package with  `Pkg.add(Taro)`. Once the package is installed, you can load it with  `using Taro; Taro.init()`. You can use `Taro.readxl()` to read excel files. The following post provides a somewhat nice tutorial on how to read excel files in Julia using Taro.jl:

https://economictheoryblog.com/2018/01/03/how-to-read-an-excel-file-in-julia-language-an-example/

Answer (score 16):

There is only one pure-Julia v1.0-compatible Excel reader available:

[XLSX.jl](https://github.com/felipenoris/XLSX.jl)

It has no dependencies on Python or Java. Install it from the package manager by typing `]add XLSX` in the console, then load it with `using XLSX`. [Here is the tutorial document](https://github.com/felipenoris/XLSX.jl/blob/master/docs/src/tutorial.md).

Comment: Maybe it should be obvious from the name of the package, but XLSX.jl does not seem to support the XLS file format. So this might not work if you need to import an old XLS file.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb indeed; as suggested here https://github.com/felipenoris/XLSX.jl/issues/142 for old XLS one may use *`ExcelReaders.jl`*

Answer (score 6):

Taro works pretty well (even if I say so myself). You need java installed on the machine, but after that, `Pkg.add(Taro)` will install all the dependencies for you. And, I think you'll have better luck with Taro with more complex excel files.

Comment: So, there's no independent Julia package?  Would there be a reason to use this instead of the ExcelReaders package if one wasn't experiencing the errors the questioner had? (Isn't python suppose to be more efficient at excel manipulations than Java?)

Answer (score 3):

If you are fine with saving in the ods format, you could also use the [OdsIO.jl](https://github.com/sylvaticus/OdsIO.jl) package.

It uses a python module (`ezodf`) as well, but it should install it automatically in both Windows and Linux when you install OdsIO.jl.

Answer (score 2):

If you can save as a `.csv` then CSV.jl works well.

Answer (score 0):

The ExcelReaders package is also available

https://github.com/davidanthoff/ExcelReaders.jl